# Apache Alias set so /rt defaults to specific location, prefer rt.example.com?

Tags: apache, vhosts

How to change an alias `/rt` to subdomain `rt.example.com` on `apache`

Currently I have virtualhsot set up on debian, on all my sites if you go to `mysite.com/r`t it will go to request-tracker.

I would like to set it up to work on the single subdomain `rt.synergysystems.co.za`

Current Vhost configuration:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

PerlSetEnv RT_SITE_CONFIG /etc/request-tracker4/RT_SiteConfig.pm

Alias /rt /usr/share/request-tracker4/html

<Location /rt>
  SetHandler modperl
  PerlResponseHandler Plack::Handler::Apache2
  PerlSetVar psgi_app /usr/share/request-tracker4/libexec/rt-server
</Location>

<Location /rt/REST/1.0/NoAuth>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>

<Perl>
  use Plack::Handler::Apache2;
  Plack::Handler::Apache2->preload("/usr/share/request-tracker4/libexec/rt-server");
</Perl>
```

Answer (score 0):

`alias /rt` means alias anything on apache `/rt` to that `document root`.

All you need to do is setup a standard `Virtualhost`, With `ServerName`, `DocumentRoot` and `Directory` like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName rt.mysite.co.za
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
DocumentRoot "/usr/share/request-tracker4/html"

<Directory /usr/share/request-tracker4/html >
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  SetHandler modperl
  PerlResponseHandler Plack::Handler::Apache2
  PerlSetVar psgi_app /usr/share/request-tracker4/libexec/rt-server
</Directory>

<Perl>
  use Plack::Handler::Apache2;
  Plack::Handler::Apache2->preload("/usr/share/request-tracker4/libexec/rt-server");
</Perl>
</VirtualHost>
```